# Pass in various functions and elements to a Objects method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is probably a long shot, but I wanted to see if this is possible - I have the following method inside my object that I created:

```
function src_observer(target_node) {
    let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            if (mutation.attributeName === 'src') {

                target_node.show();
                target_node.next().remove();

            }
        });
        observer.disconnect();
    });

    // Pass in the Observer target node & options
    observer.observe(target_node[0], {
        attributes: true,
        attributeFilter: ['src']
    });
}
```

Now I have the exact same code logic in another file, which is:

```
let target_node = videoWrapper.html(videoElement).children('iframe')[0];

// Set our Observer options
let config = {
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['src']
}
// Observe and listen for the src data attribute
let src_observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.attributeName === 'src') {

      videoWrapper.parents().eq(1).children('.onetrust_container').remove();
      videoWrapper.parent().show();
      videoWrapper.show();
      element.fadeOut(500);
      cover.fadeOut(500);

    }
  });
  src_observer.disconnect();
});
```

The only difference between them is the inner items inside `if (mutation.attributeName === 'src')`.

**Question**:
Is it possible to reuse my objects function `src_observer()` but pass in various functions and elements in between `if (mutation.attributeName === 'src')` so that way I can reuse that method and pass it other functions and elements elsewhere.

Realistically, looking at something like this:
`src_observer(target_node, { target_show_element, target_next_element, pass_in_additional_elements }` - All help will be appreciated!

Comment: That call to `observer.disconnect();` in the first code block looks like it's in the wrong place. Is it really supposed to disconnect the observer the first time **any** mutation is observed? Or is it meant to be in the `if` block above it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, it's honestly my first time using it to track a `src` attribute, I was afraid of memory leaks, so I wanted to disconnect it properly at some point, but I wasn't 100% sure. I believe it should be in the `if` block, because if it finds a match, I'd like for it to disconnect.

Comment: Yup, you'd want to put it in the `if` block.

Comment: Would I have to worry about memory leaks if it's not inside the `if` statement? I'd like to loop all the mutations and then disconnect when it got done, but I also don't want to keep it running forever, if it only disconnects once it finds a `src` attribute. Thanks man! Changing it now.

Comment: If you never see a matching mutation, then the observer will remain. If you only want to watch for a certain period of time, you might add a `setTimeout` to disconnect it even if it hasn't seen the mutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just pass in a callback:

```
function src_observer(target_node, callback) {
    let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            if (mutation.attributeName === 'src') {
                // This call to `disconnect` seemed like it should be
                // here rather than outside this block
                observer.disconnect();
                // Call the callback to do the specific work that
                // should be done when the mutation is seen
                callback(mutation);
            }
        });
    });

    // Pass in the Observer target node & options
    observer.observe(target_node[0], {
        attributes: true,
        attributeFilter: ['src']
    });
}
```

Then the first use would be:

```
src_observer(target_node, () => {
    target_node.show();
    target_node.next().remove();
});
```

And the second would be something like (it's harder to be sure here, because the two quoted bits of code cover different ground):

```
src_observer(target_node, () => {
    videoWrapper.parents().eq(1).children('.onetrust_container').remove();
    videoWrapper.parent().show();
    videoWrapper.show();
    element.fadeOut(500);
    cover.fadeOut(500);
});
```

(You could even parameterize it more by specifying a "test" callback that determines if a given mutation record matches the condition.)

Comment: Just tested, works with `function() {` instead of `() => {` - Thanks for the help man! Learned something new today, works perfectly.

Comment: @Glider - Glad you got it working! Just FWIW: It works with both, in modern environments. If you ran into an issue with the arrow function, that suggests you're having to deal with obsolete environments like IE11. :-(